# Memoir: removing headrule in chapter page

Tags: header-footer, memoir, rules

How to remove headrule in chapter page without remove of footrule, eg, rule only in foot page in all pages, but without on chapter page, but headrule in others pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\copypagestyle{rgstyle}{headings}
\makeoddhead{rgstyle}{}{}{\slshape\rightmark}
\makeevenhead{rgstyle}{\slshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{rgstyle}{R\'egis $\smiley$ \the\year}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{rgstyle}{\thepage}{}{R\'egis $\smiley$ \the\year}
% add line
\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
% fix plain
\copypagestyle{plain}{rgstyle} % overwrite plain with rgstyle
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{} % remove right header
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{} % remove left header
\pagestyle{rgstyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Memoir without headrule in chapter page}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), just like `book`, typesets the first page of `\chapter` using the `plain` page style. You must therefore reset the `plain` page style header rule after copying `rgstyle` into `plain`:

```
\copypagestyle{plain}{rgstyle} % overwrite plain with rgstyle
\makeheadrule{plain}{0pt}{0pt} % remove plain header rule
```

[image]

The second parameter to `\makeheadrule{plain}{<len>}{0pt}` could just as well have been anything less than `\textwidth`.

Comment: That is not entirely true. `\chapter` use the `chapter` pagestyle, which is an alias for `plain`. I suggest making two pagestyles. One to use for regular pages, and one (without the headrule) which the `chapter` style can be aliased to. Only edit the `plain` style if you really know what you are doing.