# Remove headrule from a specific page or from chapter's title page and keep footrule

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

i tried this answer here [memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38736/memoir-removing-headrule-in-chapter-page) but does not work in my case,I managed to remove the header but could not remove the headrule, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%to make chapter's first page fancy
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%to add horizental link to header&foofter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\itshape header}      
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}%the widht of header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}%the widht of header line
%==========to make chapter title fancy===========
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter%to make chapter titles fancy
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\normalfont}{\filright\enspace \@chapapp~\thechapter\enspace}
{20pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}%20pt the small line that close the box
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}%{}{between header and box}{space after box}
\makeatother
%====to remove the header====
\fancypagestyle{nofooter}{%
\fancyfoot{}%
}
\fancypagestyle{noheader}{%
\fancyhead{}%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Head rule}
\thispagestyle{noheader}%
\lipsum[1]
\section{Head rule}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manged to solve this issue by playing around and customizing Plain page style with help of the answer from this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89569/custom-header-footer-rules-fancyhdr)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%to make chapter's first page fancy
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%to add horizental link to header&foofter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\itshape header}      
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}%the widht of header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}%the widht of header line
%==========to make chapter title fancy===========%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter%to make chapter titles fancy
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\normalfont}{\filright\enspace \@chapapp~\thechapter\enspace}
{20pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}%20pt the small line that close the box
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}%{}{between header and box}{space after box}
\makeatother
%==========Custmizing plain page style==========%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{} %Clear Everything.
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage} %Page Number
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule height 0pt \vspace{0mm}\hrule height 0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
}
%%%%%%
%====to remove the header====
\fancypagestyle{nofooter}{%
\fancyfoot{}%
}
\fancypagestyle{noheader}{%
\fancyhead{}%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Head rule}
%\thispagestyle{noheader}%
\lipsum[1]
\section{Head rule}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

In my case i'am using different Odd and Even pages, so do not forget to move page number manually depends on the page before and after.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by make width=0

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
```

Comment: Welcoem to TeX.SE Please for a valid answer show always an **compiling** code for a fast proof and add a screenshot of the result to your answer ...